# Cannot access 'Node' before initialization

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve a singly-linked-list problem in the code below:

```
//piece of data -val;
//reference to next node-next;

class Node {
    constructor(val) {
        this.val = val;
        this.next = null;
    }
}

class SinglyLinkedList {
    constructor() {
        this.head = null;
        this.tail = null;
        this.length = 0;
    }
    push(val1) {
        var newNode = new Node(val1);
        if (!this.head) {
            this.head = newNode;
            this.tail = this.head;
        }
        else
        {
            this.tail.next=newNode;
//             this.tail=newNode
        }

    }
} 

var list2 = new SinglyLinkedList()
list2.push("hello")
list2.push(1)
// list2.push("goodbye")
 //# sourceURL=snippet:///SLL
```

When I try to run the code it responds with the error:

```
"**Cannot access 'Node' before initialization**"
```

The Screenshot is here:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gVhB.png)

Comment: I cannot reproduce, the code you posted works fine. Try in a fresh console, maybe you left `Node` uninitialised while fiddling around.

Comment: The error message doesn't make any sense. It typically comes from using a variable within the TDZ, but here, `class Node` comes at the very top.

Answer (score -1):

Just change the `Node` to `node` in the `Node` class and then change it in `push` method, then it will work. I do not know the reason I was stuck in, but I changed it then it worked.

Comment: class node {
    constructor(val) {
        this.val = val;
        this.next = null;
    }
}

class SinglyLinkedList {
    constructor() {
        this.head = null;
        this.tail = null;
        this.length = 0;
    }
    push(val1) {
        var newNode = new node(val1);
        if (!this.head) {
            this.head = newNode;
            this.tail = this.head;
        }
        else
        {
            this.tail.next=newNode;
//             this.tail=newNode
        }

    }
} 

var list2 = new SinglyLinkedList()

Comment: There is a naming convention on using classes in JavaScript, it should be `PascalCase`